# sympy-lamdify can't convert "And"

Tags: python, sympy, lambdify

I am trying to remap `And` in `sympy` when using `lambdify`, but it seems not working...

```py
import sympy
x, y = sympy.symbols('x y')
f = sympy.And(x, y)


def my_and(x, y):
    print("inside my_and")
    return x and y

f_fn = sympy.lambdify([x, y], f, {"And": my_and})
print(f_fn(True, False))
```

The result will not display "inside my_and", which means that `my_and` doesn't work.
Other functions like `sin` work well as follows. I don't where it goes wrong...

```py
import sympy
x = sympy.symbols('x')
f = sympy.sin(x)


def my_sin(x):
    print("inside my_sin")
    return 0.


f_fn = sympy.lambdify([x], f, {"sin": my_sin})
print(f_fn(0.))
```

This one will output exactly `inside my_sin` and `0.`

I want to remap `And` to my function, so what sould I do?

Answer (score 0):

`help(f_fn)` for `sin` example shows:

```
Help on function _lambdifygenerated:

_lambdifygenerated(x)
    Created with lambdify. Signature:
    
    func(x)
    
    Expression:
    
    sin(x)
    
    Source code:
    
    def _lambdifygenerated(x):
        return sin(x)
```

and after poking around as bit I found the mapping is defined the `__globals__` of this function:

```
In [224]: f_fn.__globals__.keys()
Out[224]: dict_keys(['sin', 'x', 'builtins', 'range', '__builtins__'])

In [225]: f_fn.__globals__['sin']
Out[225]: <function __main__.my_sin(x)>
```

The help for your 'and' example:

```
Help on function _lambdifygenerated:

_lambdifygenerated(x, y)
    Created with lambdify. Signature:
    
    func(x, y)
    
    Expression:
    
    x & y
    
    Source code:
    
    def _lambdifygenerated(x, y):
        return x and y
```

while there's a similar mapping:

```
In [229]: f_and.__globals__.keys()
Out[229]: dict_keys(['and', 'y', 'x', 'builtins', 'range', '__builtins__'])

In [230]: f_and.__globals__['and']
Out[230]: <function __main__.my_and(x, y)>
```

but I think this doesn't work because, `and` in `x and y` is a Python keyword, in an operator role, not a function.  It can't be mapped to something else.

It's the normal short-circuited `and` of Python:

```
In [231]: f_and(False,'foo')
Out[231]: False

In [232]: f_and(True,'foo')
Out[232]: 'foo'

In [240]: f_and(x>0,y)
...
TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational
```

---

Just realized I used `and`, while you used `And`:

```
In [241]: f_and = lambdify([x,y],f,{"And": my_and})

    def _lambdifygenerated(x, y):
        return x and y

In [242]: f_and.__globals__.keys()
Out[242]: dict_keys(['And', 'y', 'x', 'builtins', 'range', '__builtins__'])

In [243]: f_and.__globals__['And']
Out[243]: <function __main__.my_and(x, y)>
```

There's even less of a connection between the mapping and function.

Mappings like `{"And": my_and}` don't affect the code translation directly.  That is they don't produce

```
def foo(x,y):
   return my_and(x,y)   # if my_sin(x)
```

rather they determine how the Python code is run.

---

If I omit the mapping

```
f_and1 = lambdify([x,y], f)
```

the code is

```
def _lambdifygenerated(x,y):
        return logical_and.reduce((x,y))
```

`f_and1.__globals__` gives a whole raft of `numpy` functions, including

```
In [254]: f_and1.__globals__['logical_and']
Out[254]: <ufunc 'logical_and'>
```

and the behavior is `numpy` wise:

```
In [261]: f_and1([True,True],[True,False])
Out[261]: array([ True, False])
```

`lambdify([x,y],f,[{"And": my_and},'numpy'])` also gives me the `logical_and` translation.